# how to replace infinite value with maximum value of a pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, replace, infinite

I have a dataframe which looks like

```
City   Crime_Rate

A      10

B      20 

C      inf

D      15
```

I want to replace the inf with the max value of the Crime_Rate column , so that my resulting dataframe should look like

```
City   Crime_Rate

A      10

B      20 

C      20

D      15
```

I tried

```
df['Crime_Rate'].replace([np.inf],max(df['Crime_Rate']),inplace=True)
```

But python takes inf as the maximum value , where am I going wrong here ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Filter out `inf` values first and then get `max` of `Series`:

```
m = df.loc[df['Crime_Rate'] != np.inf, 'Crime_Rate'].max()
df['Crime_Rate'].replace(np.inf,m,inplace=True)
```

Another solution:

```
mask = df['Crime_Rate'] != np.inf
df.loc[~mask, 'Crime_Rate'] = df.loc[mask, 'Crime_Rate'].max()

print (df)
  City  Crime_Rate
0    A        10.0
1    B        20.0
2    C        20.0
3    D        15.0
```

Comment: Aint this fillna question?

Comment: @Dark - if need replace `np.inf` not

Answer (score 4):

Set `use_inf_as_nan` to true and then use fillna. (Use this if you want to consider `inf` and `nan` both as missing value) i.e

```
pd.options.mode.use_inf_as_na = True

df['Crime_Rate'].fillna(df['Crime_Rate'].max(),inplace=True)

   City  Crime_Rate
0    A        10.0
1    B        20.0
2    C        20.0
3    D        15.0
```

Comment: hmmm, not sure if good idea, `NaN` and `inf` are really different thing

Comment: @jezrael Just an alternative. Someday it might be helpful to someone. If I answer usual way it will be same answer as yours. So

Comment: Then add notification - it also replace NaNs if  exist :)

Comment: @Dark, Good one line solution , thank you. What I have been doing was writing another line of code to replace nan with desired value

Comment: Leave a vote if the solution was helpful and do not use this solution if you want to replace inf with some value and nan with some other value. Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks @Dark, voted helpful. Yes , in my solution , I have to replace nan with 0 :)

Comment: In using this solution, one might want to use with `with pd.option_context("mode.use_inf_as_na", True):`. This way, pandas treat NaN as per norm after exiting the `with` block. Refer to https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/options.html

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution for a whole matrix/data frame:

`highest_non_inf = df.max().loc[lambda v: v<np.Inf].max()
df.replace(np.Inf, highest_non_inf)`

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it using an additional function **replace(np.inf, np.nan)** within max().

It replaces inf  with nan for the operations happening inside max() and max returns the expected maximum value not inf

### Example below : Max value is 100 and replaces inf

```
#Create dummy data frame
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np  
a = float('Inf')
v = [1,2,5,a,10,5,a,5,100,2]  
df = pd.DataFrame({'Col_A': v})
#Data frame looks like this
In [33]: df
Out[33]: 
        Col_A
0    1.000000
1    2.000000
2    5.000000
3         inf
4   10.000000
5    5.000000
6         inf
7    5.000000
8  100.000000
9    2.000000

# Replace inf  
df['Col_A'].replace([np.inf],max(df['Col_A'].replace(np.inf, 
np.nan)),inplace=True)

In[35]: df
Out[35]: 
   Col_A
0    1.0
1    2.0
2    5.0
3  100.0
4   10.0
5    5.0
6  100.0
7    5.0
8  100.0
9    2.0
```

Hope that works !

Answer (score 0):

Use [numpy clip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.clip.html). It's elegant and blazingly fast:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": [-np.inf, +np.inf, np.nan, 4, 3]})
df["x"] = np.clip(df["x"], -np.inf, 100)
# Out:
#       x
# 0   -inf
# 1  100.0
# 2    NaN
# 3    4.0
# 4    3.0
```

To get rid of the negative infinity as well, replace `-np.inf` with a small number. NaN is always unaffected. To get the max, use `max(df["x"])`.

Comment: Wouldn't `max(df["x"])` just return `inf`?